# maximal inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(W_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian Motion. Then it is easy to get the following inequality, using the Burkholder inequality:
$\mathbb{E}\left[sup_{r\in\left[0,s\right]}\left|W_{t+r}-W_{t}\right|^{q}\right]\leq C_{q}s^{\frac{q}{2}}$.
Is it possible to get a similar result for the fractional Brownian Motion instead of the usual Brownian Motion?
I have already found some Burkholder Inequalities for the fBM but I cant really apply them to get such a result

Answer (score 1):

Try [On some maximal inequalities for fractional Brownian motions](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/~valkeila/publ/unovi.pdf) by Alexander Novikov and Esko Valkeila, *Statistics & Probability Letters*, 1999, vol. 44, issue 1, pages 47-54.

Comment: Let $(B^{H}_{t})_{{t}\geq 0}$ be a fBM. Using stationarity we have $B^{H}_{t+r}-B^{H}_{t} = B^{H}_{r}$ in law. Then i could apply Theorem 1.1, right?

Comment: And am I right, assuming, that this holds for all $H\in\left(0,1\right)$?Because Iam not considering stopping times.

Comment: Can anyone give a feedback?